# How to convert Makefile.am to Makefile.in?

Tags: compiling, gnuplot, autoconf, automake

I'm trying to install gnuplot 5.3 from github. I'm running

```
aclocal
autoheader
autoconf
automake
```

inside the package location.

This gives an error because `automake` is looking for Makefile.in and I have a bunch of Makefile.am files, supposedly `automake` should change the .am files to .in but that clearly doesn't happen. Can't run `./configure` after becuase of the same reason, how do I get the .am files to change to .in?

Comment: You should read the "`INSTALL'", "`README`" files, and probably run "`./configure`" FIRST.

Comment: The install and readme tell me to do what I did, run autoconf and then ./configure but I get an error because of the .am files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first please note that GNU Plot [is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=gnuplot) in all Ubuntu versions:

> [image: binary gnuplot package]

---

But you can compile GNU Plot from GitHub by using the followed procedure:

1. Enable *Source code* repositories in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`) and install compile-time dependencies to be completely sure that all dependencies are satisfied on compile time

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep gnuplot
   ```
2. Install needed tools

   ```
   sudo apt-get install git lua5.1
   ```
3. Clone repository and run **`./prepare`** script first (**!!! important step !!!**)

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot.git
   cd gnuplot
   ./prepare
   ```
4. Then run all usual tools:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   #make check # shows various very beautiful plots
   sudo make install
   ```

   Note: it is better to use [Checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package) (`sudo make checkinstall install`) in last step, decide by yourself.

Comment: It worked perfectly, I needed to install gnuplot via git repository because I was needing features of version 5.3 and it is not possible to install that version any other why.